# Is there a way to see exactly how much memory each XAML element uses?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

Is there a way to see exactly how much memory each XAML element uses?
I'm not sure if there is even a list anywhere on the internet. I would like to see exactly how much memory each XAML UI element requires so that I can be more selective in certain situation when choosing.

Is there a accurate way to get this information in the debugger?

Comment: This kind of memory optimisation it is not something we .NEt Programmers usually deal with. Especially in XAML UI Virtualsiation should keep the memory profile manageable (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/albulank/2009/11/12/data-and-ui-virtualization-in-wpf/). And if you actually have memory issues, you Backend Data is a thousand times more likely to be the issue. Not only will itself take up memory, it will also cause more XAML Elements to be instantiated.

Comment: And as for measuring that goes: Property Value Inheritance has the ability to save relevant amounts of Memory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance). And well if strings are in the whole thing (even during output), memory measurement becomes even harder.

Comment: The amount of memory is proportional by the number of items you are databinding to. Measure with 1, 10, 100, 1000, 1000000 items and check the allocated managed heap e.g. with MemAnalyzer (https://github.com/Alois-xx/MemAnalyzer) or the Visual Studio profiler. That way you can measure excactly how much memory per item you consume.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
Well I simply wanted to know exactly how much memory different objects require. For example, ListView, TextBlock, TextBox, StackPanel, etc.

I wanted to know if there was a way to know how much RAM these items take up, aside from additional complexities that may be introduced at runtime. 

I would like to optimize my ListView a little more and use the simplest elements I can find.

Comment: That's actually not possible, because the amount of memory for each control depends on its `ControlTemplate` and `Style`. Even a simple `TextBox` can have a complex control template, not to mention such huge things as `ListView` and `DataGrid`.

Comment: @AloisKraus - that's not always correct: virtualization might enable the reuse of UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the exact amount of memory used by each object in .net and/or WPF you have to consult a memory profiler. Visual Studio includes one (maybe only the Enterprise Version of Visual Studio) or you can use tools like dotMemory or similar. (just search for .net Memory Profiler with your favourite search engine)

Tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/04/02/diagnosing-memory-issues-with-the-new-memory-usage-tool-in-visual-studio/